# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, native

I have got a problem and I didn't understand the reason why it said that.

The problem:

TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof

I have had a variable as string. We can call it componentName. I imported some components like this: "import * as _icons from "./icons";" And I want to invite a component like this "_icons[this.props.name!]". But my ide warning to me as the error sentence

```
import {SvgIconNamespace} from "../namespaces";
import * as _icons from "./icons";
import {AbstractIconComponent} from "./icons";
import React from "react";
import {View} from "react-native";

export class Icon extends AbstractIconComponent<SvgIconNamespace.SvgIconPropsInterface, SvgIconNamespace.SvgIconStateInterface> {

        render(): React.ReactNode {

            let iconElement = React.createElement(
                _icons[this.props.name!],  // Error sentence in this line!
                { size: this.props.size!, fill: this.props.fill!},
            )

            return(
                <View>
                    { iconElement }
                </View>
            );
        }

        constructor(props: SvgIconNamespace.SvgIconPropsInterface) {
            super(props)
        }

    }
```

props.name: string = 'PlusSquareIcon'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is expecting the specific names you gave your icon exports (for example "PlusSquareIcon") and not just any `string` (the type of the `Icon` `name` prop) - this is why you are getting this error.

One way you can get around this, if you would like to keep typing `props.name` just as any string, is to cast `_icons` to an index-signature interface like this:

```
import {SvgIconNamespace} from "../namespaces";
import * as _icons from "./icons";
import {AbstractIconComponent} from "./icons";
import React from "react";
import {View} from "react-native";

interface ImportedIcons {
   [key: string]: React.FC<{size: number, fill: string}>
}

export class Icon extends AbstractIconComponent<SvgIconNamespace.SvgIconPropsInterface, SvgIconNamespace.SvgIconStateInterface> {

        render(): React.ReactNode {

            let iconElement = React.createElement(
                (_icons as ImportedIcons)[this.props.name!],  // Error sentence in this line!
                { size: this.props.size!, fill: this.props.fill!},
            )

            return(
                <View>
                    { iconElement }
                </View>
            );
        }

        constructor(props: SvgIconNamespace.SvgIconPropsInterface) {
            super(props)
        }

    }
```

Comment: My ide said that it should be like this. '(_icons as unknown as ImportedIcons)[this.props.name!],'

Comment: Can you please share your `icons` file in the question? There might be a better way to type this.